# Whats the name of this eye-shaped galaxy?

Tags: naming, definition

I would like to know the name of this eye-shaped galaxy:

[Strange eye-shaped galaxy has black-hole iris, Betsy Mason, 23.07.2009, Wired.com](https://www.wired.com/2009/07/eyegalaxy/):

[image]

Comment: [APOD 27/07/2009](https://apod.nasa.gov/apod/ap090727.html)

Comment: That link contains an answer. Please answer in the answer section.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is galaxy NGC 1097, a barred spiral galaxy in the constellation Fornax. It has been distorted by interactions with neighbouring galaxies and has a weakly active galactic nucleus, with jets coming from the nucleus. The jets contain stars from a galaxy that has recently (in astronomical terms) been cannibalized. The ring in the centre is a region of star formation, surrounding the nucleus of the galaxy at about 5000 light years.